# Как изменить размер шрифта Title? Библиотека LiveCharts WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как изменить размер шрифта Title у LineSeries в LiveCharts?
Текст слишком маленький:

```
LineSeries lineseriesT2= new LineSeries();
//Заголовок линии
lineseriesT2.Title = "T\u2082";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте ```lineseriesT2.FontSize = 15d```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает